# How to detect if an intent comes from parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

i'm looking for a cleaner way to check if an intent comes from parse, right now this is my code

```
private void intentIsFromParse() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.getString("com.parse.Data") != null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, bundle.getString("com.parse.Data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I see this is for broadcast receivers for Push notifications :)

Comment: you can filter with `intent` `action`